# Assembly MIPS: Store a string

Tags: assembly, mips

I've written some code that takes your name from the keyboard and prints it right after.

```
.data  
name: .word

.text
.globl main 
main: 

li       $v0, 8 
la       $a0, name
la       $a1, 20 
syscall

move    $s1,  $v0

li       $v0, 4
la       $a0, name
syscall


li       $v0, 10       
syscall
```

But something seems off to me, like it could be slicker by storing the name to the memory and then print it.

How is that possible?

Comment: You do store the name in memory, except you forgot to allocate space for it. `name: .word` should be `name: .space 20` (or whatever directive your assembler uses).

Comment: Just to clear things up, allocating space through the data section and allocating space for the string with the "la       $a1, 20" command are two different things, right?

Comment: `la` does not allocate space, that eventually just tells the system that you want to read at most that many bytes and you declare your buffer is big enough. But that's a lie in this case :)

Comment: is the "move    $s1,  $v0" command necessary here?

Comment: No, it isn't. According to the documentation I found, syscall 8 doesn't even return anything in `$v0`.